# need help in transforming XML to XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Alright, I am editing the original post. I guess I tried a bit much by replacing the name tags of the original XML. Anyways, here is the excerpt from the original file:

```
<EMPLOYEE_LIST>
   <EMPLOYEES>
      <EMPLOYEE>
         <EMPID>650000</EMPID>
         <FIRST_NAME>KEITH</FIRST_NAME>
         <MIDDLE_NAME>HUTCHINSON</MIDDLE_NAME>
         <LAST_NAME>ROGERS</LAST_NAME>
         <EMP_TYPE></EMP_TYPE>
         <EMP_REF_ID>500000</EMP_REF_ID>
         <JOINED_ON>2001-10-06</JOINED_ON>
         <COMMENTS>Miscellanous Comments</COMMENTS>
         <NATIONALITY>
            <VALUE>American</VALUE>
         </NATIONALITY>
         <EMP_AKA>
            <AKA_NAME>Danny</AKA_NAME>
         </EMP_AKA>
         <EMP_AKA>
            <AKA_NAME>Dan</AKANAME>
         </EMP_AKA>
         <EMP_AKA>
            <AKA_NAME>Ray</AKA_NAME>
         </EMP_AKA>
         <EMP_ADDR>
            <STREET> </STREET>
            <CITY> </CITY>
            <STATE> </STATE>
            <ZIP> </ZIP>
            <COUNTRY> </COUNTRY>
       </EMPLOYEE>
    </EMPLOYEES>
</EMPLOYEE_LIST>
```

The issue that I am facing with the above XML is that I cannot find a way to fit multiple AKA (Also Known As) attributes under a single property and the XSL that I am using for this transformation is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
        <xsl:template match="/EMPLOYEE_LIST">
            <employees>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="EMPLOYEES/node()"/>
            </employees>        
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="EMPLOYEE">
        <employee>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </employee>
        </xsl:template>

        xsl:template match="EMPLOYEE/EMPID">
        <emp_id>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </emp_id>
        </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="EMPLOYEE/FIRST_NAME">
        <f_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </f_name>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="EMPLOYEE/MIDDLE_NAME">
            <m_name>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </m_name>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="EMPLOYEE/LAST_NAME">
            <l_name>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </l_name>
        </xsl:template>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <xsl:template match="EMPLOYEE/EMP_AKA">
        <aka_list>
            <xsl:for-each select="AKA_NAME">
                <aka>
                    <xsl:for-each select=".">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </aka>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </aka_list>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above given XSL when applied to my XML gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
      <employee>
         <emp_id>111345</emp_id>
         <f_name>KEITH</f_name>
         <m_name>HUTCHINSON</m_name>
         <l_name>ROGERS</l_name>
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Danny</aka>
         </aka_list>
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Dan</aka>
         </aka_list>
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Ray</aka>
         </aka_list>
      </employee>
</employees>
```

Which is not what I am trying to achieve as I need the data in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
      <employee>
         <emp_id>111345</emp_id>
         <f_name>KEITH</f_name>
         <m_name>HUTCHINSON</m_name>
         <l_name>ROGERS</l_name>
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Danny</aka>
            <aka>Dan</aka>
            <aka>Ray</aka>
         </aka_list>
      </employee>
</employees
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Moving forward, there are elements within the XML that are in huge numbers, AKA_NAME for example.

```
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Danny</aka>
         </aka_list>
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Dan</aka>
         </aka_list>
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Ray</aka>
         </aka_list>
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Danny_2</aka>
         </aka_list>
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Dan_2</aka>
         </aka_list>
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Ray_2</aka>
         </aka_list>
```

The transformation should only carry forward top 5 and the sixth one should be truncated like:

```
         <aka_list>
            <aka>Danny</aka>
            <aka>Dan</aka>
            <aka>Ray</aka>
            <aka>Danny_2</aka>
            <aka>Dan_2</aka>
         </aka_list>
```

Comment: The output that you posted does not match the XSLT template (no AKA_LIST element in the output).

Comment: `<AKA>JOHN FILTER</ALIAS>` opens with AKA closes with ALIAS, validation error.. be sure about your input XML.

Comment: I don't understand, You have `<AKA_LIST>` in your code but `<PEOPLE>` and `<PERSON>` in your output?? Exactly which one you want??

Comment: Edited the original post with source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: solution for the complete XML.

I have tried to explain the solution using comments within the XSLT template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Ignore text nodes by default -->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <!-- Transform tag name EMPLOYEES to employees -->
    <xsl:template match="EMPLOYEES">
        <employees>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </employees>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Transform tag name EMPLOYEE to employee -->
    <xsl:template match="EMPLOYEE">
        <employee>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </employee>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Transform tag name EMPID to emp_id -->
    <xsl:template match="EMPID">
        <emp_id>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </emp_id>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Transform tag name FIRST_NAME to f_name -->
    <xsl:template match="FIRST_NAME">
        <f_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </f_name>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Transform tag name MIDDLE_NAME to m_name -->
    <xsl:template match="MIDDLE_NAME">
        <m_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </m_name>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Transform tag name LAST_NAME to l_name -->
    <xsl:template match="LAST_NAME">
        <l_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </l_name>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- When encounter the first EMP_AKA element, print itself and its following
         siblings with the same name within an aka_list element -->
    <xsl:template match="EMP_AKA[1]">
        <aka_list>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="AKA_NAME|following-sibling::EMP_AKA/AKA_NAME" mode="print"/>
        </aka_list>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Transform tag name EMP_AKA to aka -->
    <xsl:template match="AKA_NAME" mode="print">
        <aka>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </aka>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**: In case you do not want to use template modes because AKA_NAME is going to be matched elsewhere and processed in the same manner, you could replace the last two templates by these ones:

```
<!-- When encounter the first EMP_AKA element, print itself and its following
     siblings with the same name within an aka_list element -->
<xsl:template match="EMP_AKA[1]">
    <aka_list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="AKA_NAME|following-sibling::EMP_AKA/AKA_NAME" />
    </aka_list>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Exclude all EMP_AKA elements (except the first one because
     the previous template has higher precedence than this one) -->
<xsl:template match="EMP_AKA" />

<!-- Transform tag name EMP_AKA to aka -->
<xsl:template match="AKA_NAME">
    <aka>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </aka>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EMP_AKA" />
```

This code produces the same output as the previous one.

---

**UPDATE 3**: OP asked about how to limit the number of AKA_NAME elements outputted. This is a solution based on UPDATE 2. Just replace the last the templates from UPDATE 2 with

```
<xsl:template match="EMP_AKA[1]">
    <aka_list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="AKA_NAME|following-sibling::EMP_AKA[position() &lt; 5]/AKA_NAME" />
    </aka_list>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Transform tag name EMP_AKA to aka -->
<xsl:template match="AKA_NAME">
    <aka>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </aka>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EMP_AKA" />
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The OP edited the post and changed completely the XML file. The following was my previous answer (did not seem right to remove it).

If you are trying to group all the <AKA> elements into an <AKA_LIST> element (it is not clear because the output that you posted does not match the transformation), then you can use the following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Just for demo -->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <!-- Match PERSON: create the list -->
    <xsl:template match="PERSON">
        <AKA_LIST>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="NAME/AKA" />
        </AKA_LIST>
    </xsl:template> 

    <!-- Outputs the AKA element, changing the tag name -->
    <xsl:template match="AKA">
        <aka>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </aka>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which transform you source XML into:

```
<AKA_LIST>
   <aka>ROSE PETAL</aka>
   <aka>JOHN FILTER</aka>
</AKA_LIST>
```

Comment: nice solution Pablo, only using template matches and apply-templates. +1

Comment: `<xsl:template match="AKA">` not required.. coz it's not a requirement to rename.. Also a better practice would be to override identity template..

Comment: Well, we are not going to know that until OP clarify in his post what he is trying to do. I made an assumption on what he is trying to do and I posted the solution for that. I do not think we can assume if it is or it is not a requirement to rename (imagine that he is going to use XML Schema after that to validate the output XML)

Comment: You can create a chat room, so we can talk over there. Just tell me the name of the chat room.

Comment: @PabloPozo Thanks man your solution worked. Just another quick question: there are instances where a node has a huge number of aka attributes (given the source where we have 2 for one employee). Is there a way that we could restrict them to 5 regardless of their number in the original XML?

Comment: You mean AKA_NAMEs inside EMP_AKA elements or EMP_AKA elements inside employees?

Comment: You could change the following template definition: <xsl:template match="AKA_NAME"> to <xsl:template match="AKA_NAME[5 >=position()]" >. So now for each employee you are going to match the first five AKA_NAME elements.

Comment: Just in case you need to know UPDATE 2 posted by your worked for me

Comment: UPDATE 2 works but restricting the # of transformations for AKA_NAMEs isn't

Comment: I have tested both UPDATE 1 and UPDATE 2 and both of them works. I did not tested the restriction on AKA_NAME. Another question, how many AKA_NAMES can be contained in an EMP_AKA. Just one?

Comment: @PabloPozo Yeah, just one. I have edited the post with an example

Answer (score 1):

Your XSLT code actually confuses because you have some tags like `<AKA_LIST>`. So I am going by Input and Output XML samples: here is the XSLT code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PERSON">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="NAME[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NAME">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/PEOPLE/PERSON/NAME/AKA"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PEOPLE>
  <PERSON>
    <NAME>
      <REFERENCE>GOOD</REFERENCE>
      <AKA>ROSE PETAL</AKA>
      </NAME>
    <NAME>
      <REFERENCE>GOOD</REFERENCE>
      <AKA>JOHN FILTER</AKA>
      </NAME>
  </PERSON>
</PEOPLE>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PEOPLE>
  <PERSON>
    <NAME>
      <AKA>ROSE PETAL</AKA>
      <AKA>JOHN FILTER</AKA>
    </NAME>
  </PERSON>
</PEOPLE>
```

**Explanation:**

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"> ......
```

the above code copies tags from Input to output *AS IS**, Other template match override this..

```
<xsl:template match="PERSON"> ......
```

the above code copies only ONE `<NAME>` TAG (first) into output..

```
<xsl:template match="NAME">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/PEOPLE/PERSON/NAME/AKA"/>
      ......
```

the above code **copies all** `<AKA>` **tags under** `<NAME>`. Since we are copying only one `<NAME>` tag, all `<AKA>` tags appear under `<NAME>`